# Angular, Include HTML file inside other HTML

Tags: angular

I need include a HTML file inside another file, but the name of the first file is dynamic.

The name is generated by the program with  the url variables

```
<p>STUDY works!!!!!</p>
<app-study1></app-study1>
```

the **study1** should be the dynamically generated name.

The file name is dynamic because is generated by the variables pased by URL. Example:

url: **www.server.com/study/1280/4**

And my code search the file: ./study/st1280n4.html

I need load the content of ./study/st1280n4.html

```
<p>STUDY works!!!!!</p>
Content of st1280n4.html......
```

Thank's

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. Why is the file name dynamic? In your example it looks like you are trying to include a component. Are your trying to include an angular component or a plain html file generated from some other program?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is `iframe`. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: Another possibility is to load the html via the `HttpClient` and bind it to the `innerHtml` attribute of a `div`.